# Is there an easier way to ensure that the values in a list carry over from one elif statement to another?

Tags: python

I can't figure out why I haven't been able to print the contents of a list in a later section of the code, after choosing a different option within a menu I made. How would I make the contents of the list carry through?

This is for a school assessment where we are supposed to create a code in python that allows the user to choose from a menu to create a list of digital roots> I've tried appending the list that contains all the other lists within it in different places.

```
def checkAnswer():
    global userInput
    global overallList

    if userInput < "1" or userInput > "3":
        print("That isn't a valid option!")
        runAll()
    elif userInput >= "1" and userInput <= "3":
        if userInput == "1":
            print("You have chosen to create a new spirolateral.")
            spirolNumber = input("What number would you like to add as a spirolateral?")
            try:
                intValue = int(spirolNumber)
                digitValue = digital_root(intValue)
                print("Okay, adding", intValue, "as a spirolateral.")
                initialValue = digitValue # Creates a value that matches the digitValue so that it isn't lost. 
                rootList = [] # Creates an empty list to add the numbers to. 
                loopingNumber = False # SO that I can create a while loop later to determine when the number repeats.
                while loopingNumber == False: # Makes sure the loop only runs while this is false.
                    if digitValue in rootList: # Checks if digitValue is a value in the rootList list. 
                        loopingNumber = True # Changes this to true so that it stops the while loop from running.
                        print(rootList)
                    else:
                        loopingNumber = False # Ensures that the value stays false.
                    rootList.append(digitValue)
                    digitValue += initialValue
                    digitValue = digital_root(digitValue)
                overallList.append(rootList)
                print(overallList)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please use a whole number!")

        elif userInput == "2":
            print("You have chosen to edit an existing spirolateral.")
            totalLists = len(overallList)

            **editList = input(print("Which spirolateral would you like to edit? You can choose from", overallList, "Please enter a number from 0 to", totalLists))  # From here overallList doesn't print anything that was added in the area if the user would have initially entered 1.** 
            spirolNumber = input("What number would you like to change this digital root to instead?")
            try:
                int(editList)
                overallList.remove(editList)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid option!")
            try:
                intValue = int(spirolNumber)
                digitValue = digital_root(intValue)
                print("Okay, adding", intValue, "as a spirolateral.")
                initialValue = digitValue # Creates a value that matches the digitValue so that it isn't lost. 
                rootList = [] # Creates an empty list to add the numbers to. 
                loopingNumber = False # SO that I can create a while loop later to determine when the number repeats.
                while loopingNumber == False: # Makes sure the loop only runs while this is false.
                    if digitValue in rootList: # Checks if digitValue is a value in the rootList list. 
                        loopingNumber = True # Changes this to true so that it stops the while loop from running.
                        print(rootList)
                    else:
                        loopingNumber = False # Ensures that the value stays false.
                        rootList.append(digitValue)
                        digitValue += initialValue
                        digitValue = digital_root(digitValue)
                        overallList.append(rootList)
                        print(overallList)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid option!")
```

I expected the output at the very beginning of the section to print 
"Which spirolateral would you like to edit? You can choose from [[list1 contents], [list2 contents], [list3 contents], [etc]] Please enter a number from 0 to 3"
But instead the output is 
"Which spirolateral would you like to edit? You can choose from [] Please enter a number from 0 to 0"

Comment: Please update your question with the code which creates `overallList` in the first place. Also if you could remove as much code as possible whilst still leaving the problem apparent.

Comment: Well, after removing anything to do with `digital_root()` your code seems to work, in that `overallList` is retained between invocations of `checkAnswer()`.

Comment: Try sending the list to the method so that it gets carried through.